# how to get the init parameters value to debug

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I am creating a player and I am very new in C# and Silverlight. In my *App.xaml.cs* I have this method that loads the parameter from XML.

```
  private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            MainPage = new MainPage();
            this.RootVisual = MainPage;
            MainPage.mySMF.LoadInitParams(e.InitParams);
        }
```

Now in my main application which is at *MainPage.xaml.cs* I want to look for a certain `InitParams` value and if it is a certain value I want to do some task. How would I look for that value. I mean lets say that if I want it in my message box what would I write after
`MessageBox.Show(???)`; or is there another way to do it?

Appreciate all help.

Comment: Probably you're looking for `MainPage_Loaded` event within wich you can check whatever you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the value of the `InitParams` collection at any time using the property:

```
Application.Current.Host.InitParams
```

InitParams is a `Dictionary<string, string>`, so if you want to print out the key/value pairs separated by commas, you can do something like this:

```
using System.Linq;

class Helper {
  public static string GetInitParamsString() {
    return String.Join(",", Application.Current.Host.InitParams.Select (item => item.Key + "=" + item.Value))
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But when I did this  MessageBox.Show(Application.Current.Host.InitParams.ToString()); it showed me not exactly the initparams that I passed.

Comment: Ok, I modified my answer to include a method which will return the init params in a friendly string format